# Mongodb instalation error In lubuntu

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

Hello everyone I am trying to configure and run MongoDB in my system but getting this error stating that the service is MASKED.
I have tried each and every possible way to solve it but not able to solve it. Please help.
I have xfce version of ubuntu(LUBUNTU) installed in my system.

Following is the error that is encountered.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
sudo systemctl unmask mongodb
sudo systemctl start mongodb
```